# Activate :focus when the page loads with Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, onload, pseudo-element

I have a page which displays 2 buttons and 1 iframe. These 2 buttons (button A and B) control the content of the iframe. I have made a pseudo class (.button:focus) so the user can see which content is currently active in the iframe.

The page starts with A active. So what I want is that .button:focus is active for button A when the user loads the page. That way it is clear which content is currently active in the iframe.
I have looked in to using an onload function on the body, but couldn't set up the proper function.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="load">
<a class="button" href="Test_Hoover_A.html" target="Targetframe">Schets A</a>
</div>
<a class="button" href="Test_Hoover_B.html" target="Targetframe">Schets B</a> 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<iframe src="Test_Hoover_A.html" name = "Targetframe" height=700 width=900 style="border:2px solid green;" ></iframe>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}


.button:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: #555555;
color: white;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your elements an ID so that you can select them easily (or at least the `<a>` you wish to focus).

```js
document.getElementById('btnA').focus();
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.button:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a id="btnA" class="button" href="Test_Hoover_A.html" target="Targetframe">Schets A</a>

<a id="btnB" class="button" href="Test_Hoover_B.html" target="Targetframe">Schets B</a>
```

Or, if you are unable to edit the html for whatever reason you could select by href attribute:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='Test_Hoover_A.html']")[0].focus();
```

```html
<a id="btnA" class="button" href="Test_Hoover_A.html" target="Targetframe">Schets A</a>

<a id="btnB" class="button" href="Test_Hoover_B.html" target="Targetframe">Schets B</a>
```

You could do this without Javascript but you would have to change your `<a>`s to `<input type="button">`. This would allow you to use the `autofocus` property:

```html
<input type="button" class="button" href="Test_Hoover_A.html" target="Targetframe" value="Schets A" autofocus>

<input type="button" class="button" href="Test_Hoover_B.html" target="Targetframe" value="Schets B" >
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But this does not activate the pseudo class when loading the page at first.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Let me try to explain. This (https://i.imgur.com/vvqHSCU.jpg) is the page when its loaded, a frame with 2 buttons. This (https://i.imgur.com/ACyzRp4.jpg) is what is looks like when you have clicked on a button, the background color of a button changes. What I would like, since the page starts with content A displayed, that the pseudo class (:focus) is active for button A. So the user can see which map is currently active. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: And that is exactly what all three of above examples achieve. I've added your CSS to the first example so that you can see.

Comment: Really it would make much more sense to use a class that can be toggled rather than focus. Focus will be lost as soon as the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I put it all together in for example JSFiddle it does work. But when I implement it in my code, it does not. Is adding it in head between script tags enough? I'm getting this error in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null(…)

Comment: It actually does not lose focus when you click and scroll in the map. Which is the only purpose of the page. So that's a plus

Comment: You must run the code _after_ the dom is loaded. Either by using a dom ready handler or by moving your script to end of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thankyou! That what the finishing touch.